# Getting a weird error on the my first install attempt of Python

Tags: python, windows, cmd, sublimetext2

Using Sublime Text 2, but i think the problem maybe with python 2.7, or the way i installed it.

I'm getting a strange error when i compile certain things. Here's the code:

```
name = raw_input('What is your name?\n')
print 'Hi, %s.' % name
```

And heres the error:

```
What is your name?Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Python27\Practice\1.py", line 1, in <module>
    name = raw_input('What is your name?\n')
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
```

I compiled this code from pythons [wiki](http://pastebin.com/NRwkGK8S) 
and got this error half way through 'playing' the program.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Practice\1.py", line 12, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
Whats thats weird traceback error
```

I'm pretty sure its now not something to do with sublime because im running them in IEP now aswell and im getting the same errors.

Thank you

Comment: what is the full line  `num_of_games =`?

Comment: you simply missed the second bracket on line 16

Comment: @JamesKent **No**, code is perfectly okay(Syntax wise). Issue is with Sublime Text 2.

Comment: Sorry please see post for revised edition.